# The share of the labor force in GDP (including wages and transfers to social protection, %)

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, financial-economics

What do the countries with the highest value for this indicator have in common (the share of labor in GDP, including wages and transfers for social protection, %) ? Conversely, what do the countries with the lowest values for this indicator have in common?